# Joomla 2.5.6 - 403 forbidden

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, http-status-code-403

I have installed joomla 2.5.6 and created my own template. I was unable to upload it as zip so I used FTP and than installed from folder. I'm still getting error 403 Forbidden when trying to upload something or click save button anywhere in admin panel.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to check files/folders permissions at your server. This is the most often case for 403 error. 
Sorry for getting too short at the start.
Go to admin control panel -> Site -> System Information -> Directory Permissions and check that every directory is writable. Give specific attenstion to 2 strings at the bottom: Log directory and Temp directory

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you insure *all** your template files are in place, and that there are appropriate database entries in the extensions table.  The 403 error isn't necessarily from the webserver, Joomla often uses them when it doesn't find something.